# naming variables from loop jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is a follow question from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981100/jquery-loop-to-generate-variables

So i'm trying to make variables in newly created arrays in my function. Then i will have to call each newly created variable to my chart.

```
var digits = [2012, 01, 5, 88, 2012, 01, 6, 90, 2012, 05, 9, 130];
size = 3;
data = []

while (digits.length > 0)
data.push(digits.splice(0, size));
var mysize = data.length;
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  x = 0
  console.log("This is set " + i)
  console.log('This is the data for array ' + i + '\n ' + data[i])
  for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
  console.log(data[i][j])
```

MY second console.log statement prints out arrays in sets of four. I need to name each of those arrays, and then i need to be able to call each individual array in my chart, which is in a separate function.

Right now each array is named from the line

```
console.log('This is the data for array ' + i + '\n ' + data[i])
```

with no variable set from this line.

The end result should be 
    my1 = [2012,1,5,88]
    my2 = [2012, 1,6, 90]
    my3 = [2012, 5, 9, 130]
And since the data from my array could scale I wont be able to know how many new variable arrays i need to make. That's why the code should auto generate new array variable names, and break the original data into sets of four.

Then i would have to pass each newly created variable separately into my chart.

Comment: This is  better start than last question, having some code. Unfortunately still missing critical information.... name them from what? What is expected results structure?

Comment: Don't use your arrays as associative arrays, you need to convert them to object literals.

Comment: Ok, but in object literals, how will it auto generate key names?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an object, not an array. Objects have keys which you can use as an identifier.

```js
;(function(){
  'use strict';
  
const CHUNK_SIZE = 3;
let digits       = [2012, 1, 5, 88, 2012, 1, 6, 90, 2012, 5, 9, 130];
let names        = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];
let data         = {};

for(let i = 0; digits.length; i++)
  data[names[i]] = digits.splice(0, CHUNK_SIZE);

console.log(data.foo);
console.log(data.bar);
console.log(data.baz);  
  
}());
```

Also, I notice that some of your numbers start with `0`. JS will treat them as octal instead of decimal. Either remove the `0` so they become decimals or if you want to preserve it, make them strings instead.

Comment: But lets say the lets digits scales from time to time, you wont know how many names you need that why the code should auto generate variables for names.